# I'm having trouble deploying my REST API on Vercel

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, deployment, vercel

I am trying to create a Rest API using Node.js, Express, and MongoDB. I am still in the learning process. When I run my project locally, I don't see any issues. I can also successfully send get and post requests from Postman. There are no problems with saving data to the database either. However, when I deploy my project to Vercel, I encounter a 404 error, and before that, I was getting a "No Response from Serverless Function" error. Can you help me with this? For example purposes, I will provide one of my post requests, one of my get requests, and my server.js file from my project.

```js
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const story = new Story(req.body);
    const result = await story.save();
    res.json(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send("Server error");
  }
});
```

```js
router.get("/:storyId", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const story = await Story.findOne(
      { storyId: req.params.storyId },
      { storyId: 1, storyName: 1, storyDesc: 1, storyCoverImage: 1 }
    );
    if (!story) {
      return res.status(404).json({ msg: "Story not found" });
    }
    res.json(story);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server Error");
  }
});
```

Server.js

```js
// ...
// Middleware
app.use(express.json());

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("Connected to MongoDB"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

// Apply the story router to the app
app.use("/stories", storyRoutes);

// Start server
const server = app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`)
);

// Export the server instance for testing
module.exports = server;
```

And last think my vercel.json

```json
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "server.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/"
    }
  ]
}
```

I updated my Vercel file several times in different ways but nothing worked. Also when I check the Vercel logs I don't understand much.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "server.s",
      "methods": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTION"]
    }
  ]
```